# Font style text area

Tags: html, text, fonts

I am using jssor slide with  vertical thumbs in add a layer I choose text in the image area  when I put the text in there is only one standard font.Is there any way to change the font style in the text area it seems there is only a standard text like Arial I would like to use cambriai italic.

Comment: Can you provide your current code? A snippet would be great!

Comment: I assume you mean this? style="left:88px;top:241px;width:620px;height:209px;position:absolute;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:32px;line-height:1.2;text-align:center;">Text</div>
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/img_0342_960_800-s99x66.jpg" />

Comment: Have you tried adding `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;` as an attribute in the style? It's very confusing the style you provided..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. You can customize content all by yourself.

```
<div style="font-family:yourfont;">your text</div>
```